# Ruby idiom for sorting on two fields

Tags: ruby, sorting

I need the Ruby idiom for sorting on two fields. In Python if you sort a list of two-element tuples, it sorts based on the first element, and if two elements are equal then the sort is based on the second element.

One example is the following sorting code in Python (word sort from longest to shortest and consider second element to break ties) from http://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook011.html

```
txt = 'but soft what light in yonder window breaks'
words = txt.split()
t = list()
for word in words:
   t.append((len(word), word))

t.sort(reverse=True)

res = list()
for length, word in t:
    res.append(word)

print res
```

What I came up in Ruby is the following code that uses structs

```
txt = 'but soft what light in yonder window breaks'
words = txt.split()
t = []

tuple = Struct.new(:len, :word)
for word in words
    tpl = tuple.new
    tpl.len = word.length
    tpl.word =  word
    t << tpl
end

t = t.sort {|a, b| a[:len] == b[:len] ?
    b[:word] <=> a[:word] : b[:len] <=> a[:len]
    }

res = []
for x in t
    res << x.word
 end

puts res
```

I would like to know if there are better ways (less code) to achieve this stable sort.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code-review and optimization and belongs on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 5):

I think you're overthinking this.

```
txt = 'but soft what light in yonder window breaks'

lengths_words = txt.split.map {|word| [ word.size, word ] }
# => [ [ 3, "but" ], [ 4, "soft" ], [ 4, "what" ], [ 5, "light" ], ... ]

sorted = lengths_words.sort
# => [ [ 2, "in" ], [ 3, "but" ], [ 4, "soft" ], [ 4, "what" ], ... ]
```

If you really want to use Struct, you can:

```
tuple = Struct.new(:length, :word)

tuples = txt.split.map {|word| tuple.new(word.size, word) }
# => [ #<struct length=3, word="but">, #<struct length=4, word="soft">, ... ]

sorted = tuples.sort_by {|tuple| [ tuple.length, tuple.word ] }
# => [ #<struct length=2, word="in">, #<struct length=3, word="but">, ... ]
```

This is equivalent:

```
sorted = tuples.sort {|tuple, other| tuple.length == other.length ?
                                       tuple.word <=> other.word : tuple.length <=> other.length }
```

(Note that it's `sort` this time, not `sort_by`.)

...but since we're using a Struct we can make this nicer by defining our own comparison operator (`<=>`), which `sort` will invoke (the same works in any Ruby class):

```
tuple = Struct.new(:length, :word) do
  def <=>(other)
    [ length, word ] <=> [ other.length, other.word ]
  end
end

tuples = txt.split.map {|word| tuple.new(word.size, word) }
tuples.sort
# => [ #<struct length=2, word="in">, #<struct length=3, word="but">, ... ]
```

There are other options for more complex sorting. If you wanted to get longest words first, for example:

```
lengths_words = txt.split.map {|word| [ word.size, word ] }
sorted = lengths_words.sort_by {|length, word| [ -length, word ] }
# => [ [ 6, "breaks" ], [ 6, "window" ], [ 6, "yonder" ], [ 5, "light" ], ... ]
```

Or:

```
tuple = Struct.new(:length, :word) do
  def <=>(other)
    [ -length, word ] <=> [ -other.length, other.word ]
  end
end

txt.split.map {|word| tuple.new(word.size, word) }.sort
# => [ #<struct length=6, word="breaks">, #<struct length=6, word="window">, #<struct length=6, word="yonder">, ... ]
```

As you can see, I'm relying a lot on Ruby's built-in ability to sort arrays based on their contents, but you can also "roll your own" if you prefer, which might perform better with many, many items. Here's a comparison method that's equivalent to your `t.sort {|a, b| a[:len] == b[:len] ? ... }` code (plus a bonus `to_s` method):

```
tuple = Struct.new(:length, :word) do
  def <=>(other)
    return word <=> other.word if length == other.length
    length <=> other.length
  end

  def to_s
    "#{word} (#{length})"
  end
end

sorted = txt.split.map {|word| tuple.new(word.size, word) }.sort
puts sorted.join(", ")
# => in (2), but (3), soft (4), what (4), light (5), breaks (6), window (6), yonder (6)
```

Finally, a couple comments on your Ruby style:

1. You pretty much never see `for` in idiomatic Ruby code. `each` is the idiomatic way to do almost all iteration in Ruby, and "functional" methods like `map`, `reduce` and `select` are also common. Never `for`.
2. A great advantage of Struct is that you get accessor methods for each property, so you can do `tuple.word` instead of `tuple[:word]`.
3. Methods with no arguments are called without parentheses: `txt.split.map`, not `txt.split().map`

Comment: Thanks, Jordan for the detailed response. I quickly checked just the last snippet and it gave the proper output. For reverse sort, I just had to add .reverse. Will go through all your suggestions and see what's the best that will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby makes this easy, using [Enumerable#sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) will and [Array#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3Ehttp://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for sorting.

```
def sort_on_two(arr, &proc)
  arr.map.sort_by { |e| [proc[e], e] }.reverse
end

txt = 'but soft what light in yonder window breaks'

sort_on_two(txt.split) { |e| e.size }
  #=> ["yonder", "window", "breaks", "light", "what", "soft", "but", "in"]

sort_on_two(txt.split) { |e| e.count('aeiou') }
  #=> ["yonder", "window", "breaks", "what", "soft", "light", "in", "but"]

sort_on_two(txt.split) { |e| [e.count('aeiou'), e.size] }
  #=> ["yonder", "window", "breaks", "light", "what", "soft", "but", "in"]
```

Note that in recent versions of Ruby, `proc.call(e)` can be written `proc[e]`, `proc.yield(e)` or `proc.(e)`.

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution for sorting on two fields. The first field need not be the length of the second element. In the example I gave it happened to be so. My actual requirements are sorting (like Python tuple.sort) of elements that are distances (num) and names (strings). This sort is required in computing the nearest neighbor in a machine learning algorithm for collaborative filtering.

Comment: Since "breaks", "window", "yonder" are all of size 6, when we reverse sort, the correct output is: ["yonder", "window", "breaks", "light", "what", "soft", "but", "in"]

Comment: I edited to provide the ordering you want.  Note that other orderings can be obtained by flipping signs between + and - and/or removing `.reverse`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Your style is a bit like Perl, in my humble opinion. Will take time to digest.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: my first answer was wrong (this time!), thanks to @mu is too short comment

Your code is ok to sort on two criteria, but if you just want to achieve the same result, the best is to do the following:

```
txt.split.sort_by{|a| [a.size,a] }.reverse
=> ["breaks", "window", "yonder", "light", "soft", "what", "but", "in"]
```

The first check will use the size operator, and if the result is zero, it will use the second one....

If you really want to keep your data structure, it's same principle:

```
t.sort_by{ |a| [a[:len],a[:word]] }.reverse
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean @diego.greyrobot?

Comment: `0` isn't falsey in Ruby so that `||` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @muistooshort you are right, I've answered too quickly, thanks